# Sort options alphabetically in JS select list

Tags: javascript, list, sorting, select

I have a form that is sort alphabetically when it loads options first time the webpage is loaded, with form options sorted via mysql, this works until i change one of the parent options. If i change the parent option, child options loses the alphabetical order and are listed with a weird order that I think is ordered by id.

I have this code, maybe I should add something to it in order to JS sort form options?

```
if($Localities){
    foreach ( $Localities as $item ) {
        $mitems[] = $item;
    }
}
$javascript = '';

$ComboLocation        = JHTML::_('select.genericlist',   $mitems, 'lid', 'class="inputbox select" size="1" '.$javascript,'id', 'name',  $row->lid); 
return $ComboLocation;
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your trying to sort a javascript array Alphabetically if so you can use the sort(); method.

```
var JavascriptArrayVar = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
JavascriptArrayVar.sort();
/* Array is now Apples Banana Mango Orange*/
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AFGt7/)

If not, let me know what you are looking to accomplish.

Comment: yes, that is exact. Can you help me to modify the code above because I am not a programmer? Thank!

Comment: Your code doesn't have javascript in it. If you share your JS code and what you've tried I'd be happy to help there. However it looks like PHP is the main part of your code. If you want to sort in PHP its, sort($Localities)